# Can Angel/Archangel swim?

Tags: marvel, x-men, mutant

Warren Worthington III, the X-Man known as both Angel and Archangel, has the mutant ability of flight via feathered and/or techno-organic wings. His mutant powers include superhuman strength in his wings, hollow bones and 0% body fat to account for his being capable of flight.

If he has 0% body fat wouldn't that create zero buoyancy similar to how gorillas are unable to swim for the same reason? Has he ever been depicted swimming in any of the comics?

I'm looking for an answer dealing specifically with the comics continuity as that is the only one (to my knowledge) that has stated the 0% body fat point.

Comment: I read a description of a guy who has wings, hollow bones, 0% body fat, and can fly, and my first thought is, "Isn't a body fat percentage that low really unhealthy?" Is that weird?

Comment: Mutant powers warp reality and physics, having a healthy body with 0% body fat is child's play for the x gene. No accounting for magic.

Comment: [Gorillas can swim](http://www.livescience.com/39039-apes-swimming-video.html) and semi-hollow bones like birds would decrease density, which aids in floating, such as the rock [pumice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumice), which can float

Comment: @CreationEdge a chimpanzee and an orangutan are *not* gorillas. The problem is that muscle is much denser than fat, with no body fat at all and the amount of muscle and added weight of the wings would cause him to naturally sink. You do have a point about hollow bones though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, Warren can swim**. I can't find a scan of it, but he has been shown swimming a few times in the 616 continuity. In fact, the Xavier Institute has always had an Olympic-size pool which is frequently used by ALL of the X-Men for exercise and physical therapy purposes. During the course of his life with the X-Men, he has also found himself submerged in the ocean and/or a flooded environment more than once (usually at the hands of some villain or related destruction).

In Ultimatum #1, the Ultimate version of Angel was forced to test this theory in order to rescue an unconscious Dazzler from the flooded streets of New York. The panels below depict the scene where the Ultimate version of Angel discovers for the first time that he can, in fact, swim underwater, despite all evidence to the contrary:

[image]

Comment: “Take that, science and logic!” The motto of all great comic books.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Especially when used like this. "I can fly? Well, yeah, duh, that's obvious. Wait, I can *swim*? That's just crazy!"